# The acceleration won't add on

Tags: java

So I have a little piece of code here. What the code is supposed to do:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class squareMovingUsingArrowKeys extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
static int x;
static int y;
static double acceleration=0.3;
static int originSpeed;
static int actualSpeed;
static boolean a=false;
Timer timer;
squareMovingUsingArrowKeys() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    acceleration = 0.3;
    actualSpeed = 1;
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    a = true;
    System.out.println(actualSpeed);
    actualSpeed+=acceleration;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        x -= actualSpeed;
    } 
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        x += actualSpeed;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        y -= actualSpeed;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        y += actualSpeed;
    }
    //first call move to update x and y and later repaint that JPanel
    move(x, y);
    repaint();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(125,125,255));
    g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(new Color(100,255,100));
    g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(x>=500){
        x=500;
    }else if(y>=500){
        y=500;
    }else if(x<=0){
        x=0;
    }else if(y<=0){
        y=0;
    }
}
public void start() {
    keyPressed(null);
    paintComponent(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Moving");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    squareMovingUsingArrowKeys m = new squareMovingUsingArrowKeys();
    f.add(m);
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.addKeyListener(m);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    originSpeed = 1;
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

- Be able to "accelerate" as you hold a button

- Stop when the x or y is at 500
- Move in secondary directions

But obviously, it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by stop? stop to accelerate? and what do you mean by secondary direction?

Comment: Stop completely, and secondary directions are diagonal directions.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How does the not working manifest itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `actualSpeed` variable is an int and you are trying to add 0.3 to it which is a double and less than 1. If it would have been greater than 1 let's say 1.2, then java would have added 1 to your `actualSpeed`.

Change type of `actualSpeed` to double and it will work as you cannot add doubles or floating point to an int.

I will also recommend you to read about primitive data types of Java.

For stopping when x = 500 or y = 500. You need to use an if statement inside your keyhandler which checks that both x && y are less than 500 else it won't accelerate. For moving diagonally. Your green dot does move diagonally on my system.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't catch that! What about #2&3?

Comment: Like, actualSpeed= 0 for x or y being 500

Comment: I am not sure whether you are asking this or telling me to do it. But mainly its basic if statement. When you increase acceleration, add an extra if statement to check if x and y are less than 500, if yes then accelerate else do whatever you want to.